# swagger 2.6.1 /swagger-resources/configuration/ui 404

Tags: spring, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to add Swagger to the Spring Framework, but I get a 404 error.

My project setting 
Spring 4.2.5 + Spring Security 4.2.3

**pom.xml**

```xml
<!-- Swagger2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Swagger-UI -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration 
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport { 
    @Bean public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2) 
                .select() 
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()) 
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()) 
                .build() 
                .apiInfo(apiInfo()) 
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false); 
    }
    /** API Info */ 
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() { 
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("Swagger Sample", "APIs Sample", "Sample Doc 0.1v", "", "Author Name", "This sentence will be display.", "/"); 
        return apiInfo; 
    } 

    /** Swagger UI 를 Resource Handler 에 등록 */ 
    @Override 
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) { 
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html") .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/"); 
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**") .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"); 
    } 

}
```

**context-security.xml**

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/swagger-ui.html" />
<intercept-url pattern="/swagger-resources" />
<intercept-url pattern="/webjars/** " />
<intercept-url pattern="/v2/api-docs" />
```

[image: Error page]

[image: Dev console]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help you. I use Spring Mvc, swagger2 and don´t use spring security.

Separate the configuration into 2 parts

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    @ComponentScan("com.demo.controller")
    public class SwaggerConfig{

        @Bean
        public Docket apiSwagger(){
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build();
        }

    }
```

Next, I create another class of configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
public class AppSwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //enabling swagger-ui part for visual documentation
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

Finally, in my WebAppInitializer class, add the AppSwaggerConfig class in the Dispatcher

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(SwaggerConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        try {
            loadProperties(rootContext);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Properties could not be loaded", e);
        }

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(AppSwaggerConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem, new Docket requires also defining few parameters. In my old project:

```
@Bean
public Docket configSwaggerApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .apiInfo(new ApiInfo(environment.getProperty("api.title"), environment.getProperty("api.description"), environment.getProperty("api.version"),
                environment.getProperty("api.terms"), new Contact(environment.getProperty("api.contact.name"), environment.getProperty("api.contact.url"),
                environment.getProperty("api.contact.mail")), environment.getProperty("api.license"), environment.getProperty("api.license.url")))
        .host(environment.getProperty("platform.url"))
        .pathMapping(environment.getProperty("server.context-path"))
        .protocols(newHashSet("http", "https"))
        .produces(Arrays.stream(new String[] {"application/json"}).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
        .tags(new Tag("public", "public tools"), new Tag("user","user tools"));
}
```

If you use Spring Security, don't forget to provide non-secured access to swagger:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/swagger*", "/swagger.json", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-*/**", "/webjars/**");
}
```

Default path `/v2/api-docs` does not require any interceptors and configurations. If you want to change it, add to `application.properties` new parameter `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/new/path`.

Resource handlers are used if you don't use Spring Boot.

If these advices won't help you, I can describe fully workable version with oauth security access.

Comment: I mistake Web.xml servlet action just .do